# Porch ceiling - should I insulate it?

Tags: ceiling, porch

What would you recommend to do with the porch ceiling that looks like on the picture?

[image]

I would like to insulate it, because wind blows in. I am not sure how much insulation should I put there. I guess Energy Performance Certificate (EPC) is a consideration (I live in England), but on the other hand porch insulation is probably irrelevant, since I have a second door anyway.

All suggestions welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I recall that opinion-based questions like "What would you recommend" might be considered off topic on this site. You could edit your question to, "I think I'd like to do thus and such, will it work?" then the question may be OK.

Comment: If wind blows in, I'd recommend sealing anywhere that happens before insulating and finishing the ceiling.

Comment: Is that brown thing at the top of the picture a piece of plywood fastened to the rafters?

Comment: If the rafters are always exposed then you should fix that. Then fix air leaks with seals. Then replace joinery wito double or triple glazing. Finally worry about insulation.

Answer (score 1):

If the porch is enclosed, and its air is heated or cooled  directly or indirectly from an adjacent room, yes you should consider steps to insulate the room.

If it's drafty as you say, that's the first thing you should address. Figure out where the drafts are coming from and take appropriate steps to seal them.

We don't know what you mean by "second door".  If it is to the outside, then obviously, close it. Otherwise explain the relevance in the question.

If you plan to do all that and create a space that is more indoors than outdoors, then yes for sure it would benefit from roof insulation.